# DriverPackagePreinstall to work on 64 bit (compiled to 32 bit)

Tags: c#, windows-installer, pinvoke, 32bit-64bit, drivers

Is there a way I can compile an application which calls the `DriverPackagePreinstall()` (using Pinvoke) in such a way that it can work on 64-bit devices (Windows 7) even though it's targeted to 32bit?

The reason being it will be run as part of an installer of a much bigger application (using Windows Installer Project), which will target 32 bit but must run on a 64 bit platform also.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MyDriver
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            if (args.Count() == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please specify filename!");
                return;
            }


            int result= DriverPackagePreinstall(args[0], 0);


            if (result == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Success");
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: 0x{0}", result.ToString("X8"));
            }

        }

        [DllImport("DIFxAPI.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern Int32 DriverPackagePreinstall(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string DriverPackageInfPath,
            Int32 Flags);

        }
    }
}
```

If I build this targeting x86, and try to run on a 64-bit machine, I get error `E0000235` (`ERROR_IN_WOW64`). This error goes away if I build targeting x64.

Now I don't mind compiling it twice and letting the installer decide which to install based on the platform it's being installed to. However, if I try to build the installer while including the 64-bit version I get the error,

`263    File 'MyDriver.x64.exe' targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'`

Alternatively a way of getting the Installer to overlook this error at build time (and run it anyway when the project is installing) would be good.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by adding both the 64-bit and 32-bit versions of the application to a self-extracting zip-file together with a batch file which decides which one to execute.

The self-extractor is a 32-bit exe so as long no one tells Visual Studio that it contains a 64-bit one, it works.