# Installing a x64 bit driver from a x86 app

Tags: c++, winapi, driver, umdf

I have an UMDF driver which currently is redistributed through 2 standalone installers, one for x64 and one for x86.

The install driver function is this one, copied from devcon:

```
bool InstallDriver(const TCHAR* InfPath, const wchar_t* TargetID)
{
#define MAX_CLASS_NAME_LEN    32
    GUID ClassGUID = {};
    TCHAR ClassName[MAX_CLASS_NAME_LEN] = {};
    TCHAR hwIdList[LINE_LEN + 4] = {};

    //
    // List of hardware ID's must be double zero-terminated
    //
    ZeroMemory(hwIdList, sizeof(hwIdList));
    if (FAILED(StringCchCopy(hwIdList, LINE_LEN, TargetID)))
    {
        return false;
    }


//
// Use the INF File to extract the Class GUID.
//
    if (!SetupDiGetINFClass(InfPath, &ClassGUID, ClassName, sizeof(ClassName) / sizeof(ClassName[0]), 0))
    {
        return false;
    }
//
// Create the container for the to-be-created Device Information Element.
//
    HDEVINFO DeviceInfoSet = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    DeviceInfoSet = SetupDiCreateDeviceInfoList(&ClassGUID, 0);
    if (DeviceInfoSet == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return false;
    }


//
// Now create the element.
// Use the Class GUID and Name from the INF file.
//
    SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData;
    DeviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);
    if (!SetupDiCreateDeviceInfo(DeviceInfoSet,
        ClassName,
        &ClassGUID,
        NULL,
        0,
        DICD_GENERATE_ID,
        &DeviceInfoData))
    {
        SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(DeviceInfoSet);
        return false;
    }

//
// Add the HardwareID to the Device's HardwareID property.
//
    if (!SetupDiSetDeviceRegistryProperty(DeviceInfoSet,
        &DeviceInfoData,
        SPDRP_HARDWAREID,
        (LPBYTE)hwIdList,
        (lstrlen(hwIdList) + 1 + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR)))
    {
        SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(DeviceInfoSet);
        return false;
    }

//
// Transform the registry element into an actual devnode
// in the PnP HW tree.
//
    if (!SetupDiCallClassInstaller(DIF_REGISTERDEVICE,
        DeviceInfoSet,
        &DeviceInfoData))
    {
        SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(DeviceInfoSet);
        return false;
    }

//
// update the driver for the device we just created
//
    if (!UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices(0, TargetID, InfPath, INSTALLFLAG_FORCE, 0))
    {
        int y = GetLastError();
        if (y == ERROR_IN_WOW64 || y == ERROR_NO_SUCH_DEVINST || y == ERROR_NO_SUCH_DEVINST || y == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        {

        }
        SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(DeviceInfoSet);
        return false;
    }


    SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(DeviceInfoSet);
    return true;
}
```

This works OK, but I want to have a single x86 redistributable which would contain both the x86 and x64 drivers and detect if running in WOW64 and install the x64 driver.

This time the `InstallDriver` function fails at this call:

```
if (!SetupDiCallClassInstaller(DIF_REGISTERDEVICE,
    DeviceInfoSet,
    &DeviceInfoData))
{
    SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(DeviceInfoSet);
    return false;
}
```

Last error 3758096949.

I couldn't find more info on that error, plus I didn't see any tip in [SetupDiSetDeviceRegistryProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdisetdeviceregistrypropertya?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(SETUPAPI%2FSetupDiSetDeviceRegistryProperty)%3Bk(SetupDiSetDeviceRegistryProperty)%3Bk(DevLang-C%2B%2B)%3Bk(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396) to set the registry to the x64 one, like in RegCreateKeyEx's KEY_WOW64_64KEY flag.

Is there a way to avoid the 2 executables?

Comment: 3758096949 is 0x‭E0000235‬ see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41834535/driverpackagepreinstall-to-work-on-64-bit-compiled-to-32-bit

Comment: you got `ERROR_IN_WOW64` from [`UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevicesW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/newdev/nf-newdev-updatedriverforplugandplaydevicesw) - *The calling application is a 32-bit application attempting to execute in a 64-bit environment, which is not allowed.*. unfortunately this is by design if you need use this api

Comment: Move the installation code to a 64bit app, then launch that from your 32bit app